# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Double

Tags: java, hibernate, double

I want to select records from db by matching a Double value.

The code is as below:

```
String aQuery = "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE field_a = :fieldA";

SQLQuery thisQuery = session.createSQLQuery(aQuery).addEntity(AClass.class);
thisQuery.setEntity("fieldA", aDoubleValue);
```

**a.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="AClass" table="a_table">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="pguuid" access="field">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="fieldA" column="field_a"type="double" />
    ....
</class>
```

Then got this issue
**org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Double**

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aren't you supposed to use `setParameter` instead of `setEntity`?

```
thisQuery.setParameter("fieldA", aDoubleValue);
```